# MathJax: Have \displaystyle apply to each case of \begin{cases}

Tags: cases, mathjax, displaystyle

I would like `\displaystyle` to apply to each of my `cases`:

```
$$\begin{cases} \displaystyle
  \frac 1 2 \\
  \frac 3 4
\end{cases}$$
```

But it only seems to apply to the first:

[image: Cases example]

How can it be applied to all cases?

Comment: While [tag:MathJax] uses LaTeX syntax, it uses Javascript and HTML's DOM model rather than TeX technology, making it mostly off topic for this site. If the answer doesn't work, you might try instead searching among the [questions tagged with mathjax on Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathjax), or in the official [mathjax-users](https://groups.google.com/d/forum/mathjax-users) Google group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add `\displaystyle` to every line.

```
$$\begin{cases}
  \displaystyle \frac 1 2 \\
  \displaystyle \frac 3 4
\end{cases}$$
```

[<kbd>Live example</kbd>](http://mathb.in/145889)

Answer (score 7):

Use `dfrac` instead of `frac`:

```
\[
\begin{cases}
  \dfrac{1}{2} \\[.5em]
  \dfrac{3}{4}
\end{cases}
\]
```

[image]

---

[LIVE PREVIEW](http://mathb.in/145891)

---

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for MathJax.

Comment: @TomHale I didn't know. I changed the answer. See if it works now.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative with a different fraction form, which also saves vertical space:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{cases}
  1/2 \\
  3/4
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]